# how to get user uid from firebase database and print it on the table

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Please help me get the user UID from firebase.  How can I retrieve the user uid and show it on the table?  I cannot delete it and update.  Please tell me how.

```js
 
function readTask(){
    var UserInformation= firebase.database().ref("UserInformation/");
    UserInformation.on("child_added",function(data) {
        var taskValue= data.val();
        function tabappend(id, name, gender, email, phone, bloodType, birthday) {

            // playerlist is the ID of the table
            var tab = document.getElementById('table');
            var row = tab.insertRow(-1);    // append to table
            var id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);  
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
            var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);  

            cell0.innerHTML = id;
            cell1.innerHTML = name;
            cell2.innerHTML = gender;
            cell3.innerHTML = email;
            cell4.innerHTML = phone;
            cell5.innerHTML = bloodType;
            cell6.innerHTML = birthday;

            if (ready == true) {
                cell2.innerHTML = "&#x2713;";
                cell2.class = "ready";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML+=`
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>${taskValue.id}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.name}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.gender}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.email}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.phone}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.bloodType}</td>
            <td>${taskValue.birthday}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>   
            `
    });
}
```

Comment: the table shows undefined in my web app.

Comment: 3XQz3tmjT1VB6rbwEUi16wyrcKp2
birthday: 
"9/30/1990"
bloodType: 
"AB+"
email: 
"jcole@gmail.com"
gender: 
"Male"
name: 
"Jermaine Cole"
phone: 
"0923"